# iTunes Connect: "Release This Version" button is disabled

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

my app is in `Pending Developer Release` state, but the `Release This Version` button is disabled, why ?
the app has been set to be manually released to the store.

p.s. I am signed in with an `Admin` role.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why Save is enabled? Are there are new changes to page description etc? Can you please try to click save once and see it makes the "Release This Version" enabled?

Comment: it's just enabled for no reason, once I open the page for the first time it is already enabled ...

Comment: can you please tell what is listed on " Status History" page as last entry?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a dashboard bug just associated to your account. Contact Apple via: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs
and select "iTunes Connect Upload or General Error help" option. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue today and I am logged in with Admin role. Seems to be a bug in the web interface.

However I was able to release the new version from iTunes Connect iOS app.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the reason, our account type is Apple Developer Program / Organization, and only the `Team Agent` user can release the version, this user has a role named `Admin, Legal` which sounds has a higher level than the regular `Admin` role.

Apple docs is confusing, it says:
`The Admin role can perform all tasks in iTunes Connect, except sign contracts`

Answer (score 0):

**This is iTunes website bug - > use iTunes Mobile App instead**

I've experienced this issue once on deployment night and spent long time trying different browsers and desktop machines however without success.

I end up downloading iTunes Mobile App on my phone and releasing App using it – that worked. Since then I use Mobile App as a second option in case iTunes website is bugging up again.